# Are the following proofs regarding the intersection of a finite collection of open sets being open equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

As the title states, I'm looking to understand whether the following proofs are equally valid given the stated proposition!  The first proof uses neighborhood notation, the second proof uses open ball notation, and the third proof uses a more general norm notation.  I expect the first and second to be generally equivalent, so most interested in whether the final proof is valid as well.

**Proposition.** The intersection of a finite number of open sets is open.

*Proof 1.* Let $K = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}K_{i}$.  For any $x \in K$, there exists neighborhoods $N_{i}$ of $x$ with radii $\epsilon_{i}$, such that $N_{i} \subset K_{i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.  Then $\epsilon = min(\epsilon_{1}, ..., \epsilon_{n})$ and let $N$ be the neighborhood of $x$ with radius $\epsilon$.  Then $N \subset K_{i}$ for some $1 \leq i \leq n$, such that $N \subset K$ and $K$ is open.

*Proof 2.* Let $K = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}K_{i}$.  For any $x \in K$, there exists $S_{i}(x, \epsilon_{i}) = \{y: ||x - y|| < \epsilon_{i}\}$, such that $S_{i}(x, \epsilon_{i}) \subset K_{i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.  Then $\epsilon = min(\epsilon_{1}, ..., \epsilon_{n})$ and let $S(x, \epsilon) = \{y: ||x - y|| < \epsilon\}$.  Then $S(x, \epsilon) \subset K_{i}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, and $S(x, \epsilon) \subset K$ and $K$ is open.

*Proof 3.* Let $K = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}K_{i}$.  For any $x \in K$, $x \in K_{i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.  Given all $K_{i}$ are open, for $x \in K_{i}$, all $y$ such that $||y - x|| < \epsilon_{i}$ for some $\epsilon_{i} > 0$ are also in $K_{i}$.  Then $\epsilon = min(\epsilon_{1}, ..., \epsilon_{n})$ and for all $x \in K$, all $y$ such that $||y - x|| < \epsilon$ are also in $K$.  Thus, $K$ is open.

Comment: What definition of "open set" are you using?  That's important because in general topology, part of the definition of a topology is that the intersection of two open sets (and therefore, by induction, the intersection of finitely many open sets) is open.  But yes, the three proofs yo write appear to be equivalent.

Comment: @RobertShore thank you.  Yes, these were written as a sort of preamble to the introduction of topological space.  So while the context is to topology, the idea was to not take the intersection of two open sets being open as a given!

Comment: So you're working specifically within a metric space, and your definition of "open set" is a set for which every point within the set is contained in an open ball fully contained within the set?

Comment: @RobertShore yes, exactly!